# Infopath dropdown and populate a text with email and submit to that email

Tags: infopath, dropdown, auto-populate

Morning,

PLEASE HELP - going mad. I been trying to work this problem out for days

I want to set up an info path form so that when I drop down the ACos Yr group (7-13) (from the sharepoint database) it will select the ACo Email address from the Sharepoint database and then when I select the submit button it will have the email pop up with the email address already populate, but for all my research and trying I cannot get the email box to populate. The drop down works fine.
Any help much appreciated. 
Thank you for your help

[image: Infopath form]

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect that list as a secondary data source with query filter based on the Year Group selection and then default that filed value to the result of that query.